# Initialize 2 dim array NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

For C I would init an array like this:

NSInteger x[3][10];  That works.

Below I have  a one dim array that works.  Would like to move all of this to a 2 dim array,  How do I init it? So in other words take the code below and make it work with 2 dimensions.

```
NSMutableArray *SRData;

SRData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


NSMutableDictionary *SRRow;

SRRow = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[SRRow setObject:@"Read" forKey:@"Descr"];
[SRRow setObject:@"Read2.png" forKey:@"Img"];

[SRRow setObject:@"Read the codes" forKey:@"Det"];

[SRData addObject:SRRow] ;   

[SRRow release];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Objective-C, you just have to have an array of arrays to get the second dimension. To my knowledge, there is no shorthand, so you're stuck doing something like the following:

```
NSMutableArray *firstDimension = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    NSMutableArray *secondDimension = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [firstDimension addObject:secondDimension];
}
```

So all you would do is add your other objects (in your case, the `NSMutableDictionary`s) to the `secondDimension` array. Usage would be like:

```
[[firstDimension objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0];
```

---

**Edit**

Full code example:

```
NSMutableArray *SRData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //first dimension
NSMutableArray *SRRow = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //second dimension
[SRData addObject:SRRow]; //add row to data
[SRRow release];

NSMutableDictionary *SRField = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; //an element of the second dimension
[SRField setObject:@"Read" forKey:@"Descr"];
//Set the rest of your objects

[SRRow addObject:SRField]; //Add field to second dimension
[SRField release];
```

Now, to get at that "field" you would use code such as the following:

```
[[SRData objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the first element in the first array (the second dimension)
```

Comment: It's true there is no convenient shorthand. If you're doing a lot of this, inline functions can sometimes be helpful (`Get(array, x, y)`), and in some cases just using a C array rather than `NSArray` (C arrays of `id` are slightly trickier with ARC, but still legal.)

Comment: I can't seem to get my head around this exactly. When I first read this is makes sense but now I am trying to code it I have got lost.  Could someone how me how I would take my code above and add the 2 dimensions?  I thought Ryans example is great and I think I am almost there, but just cant grasp it without seeing a full example... thanks for any help!

Comment: Added more clarification. If you need me to be more explicit, you'll have to specify what in particular you are having a hard time with.

Comment: @MarkWorsnop: The primary issue seems to be that what you're calling a "row" is actually the individual elements. Instead, the rows should also be NSMutableArrays. So each column is an NSArray of NSArrays, and each row is an NSArray of NSDictionaries.

Comment: Thanks very much!  I was just having a heck of a time without seeing an example! I really do appreciate your efforts!  thanks again!!!